# XML Deserialization error

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am currently working with an xml file which usually should contain a list of custom objects (List), but from time to time can simply contain a string node with a message. I have a code which deserializes this file:

```
private T DeserializeFile<T>(string filePath)
    {
        StreamReader readFileStream = new StreamReader(@filePath);
        var serializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        return (T)serializerObj.Deserialize(readFileStream); 
    }
```

This works for List but for simple string throws an error (InvalidOperationException - Root element is missing, or " was not expected."). How can I detect the case when the file contains only the string element and return null from the function?

Basically this is what I want to do:

```
private T DeserializeFile<T>(string filePath)
    {
        StreamReader readFileStream = new StreamReader(@filePath);
        var serializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        try
        {
            return (T)serializerObj.Deserialize(readFileStream); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Can't you simply check file contents for XML before sending them to `XmlDeserialize()`?

Comment: How to check the content?

Comment: You already have `StreamReader` object. Just use its `ReadToEnd()` to get the entire file content in a string and then check for xml nodes using simple string functions or regex.

Comment: Well I was looking for something simpler, like returning null or something (returning null doesn't really work). This is a general method and I prefer not to insert particular cases in it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're trying to do. It uses [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load and parse the file, so that it can check if there are any elements before trying to deserialize it.

```
private T DeserializeFile<T>(string filePath)
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
    if (xdoc.Root.Elements().Any())
    {
        var serializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializerObj.Deserialize(xdoc.CreateReader());
    }
    else
        return default(T);
}
```

This assumes that you always have valid XML files, with the only difference being whether the root contains more elements or just text, e.g. a list like

```
<someRoot>
  <someObj>
  </someObj>
  <someObj>
  </someObj>
</someRoot>
```

And a "string" like

```
<someRoot>just a string</someRoot>
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. I am calling the method like this: List<CustomObject> structure = DeserializeFile<List<CustomObject>>(_reportPath); and here I am interested to get a null value or an empty list if the xml file contains a simple string node instead of more complex nodes of type CustomObject

Comment: It does return `null` with the test data I've got (that's what `default(T)` is when `T` is a `class`). I posted examples of that; is your data some other format that's incompatible with my code?